# How do I make Visitor Pattern more extensible by making subtype elements require specific subtype visitors via generics?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have the following setup defined as follows:

```
public interface Element {
    public <R> R accept(Visitor<R> visitor);
}

public interface Visitor<R> {

}

class SpecificElement implements Element {
    @Override                                    // ERROR: didn't override accept in parent
    public <R> R accept(SpecificVisitor visitor) {
        return visitor.visitSpecificElement(this);
    }
}

class SpecificVisitor implements Visitor<Boolean> {
    public Boolean visitSpecificElement(SpecificElement element) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I change the setup above such that I can require subtype `SpecificElement` to only accept `SpecificVisitor` and able to override parent class' `accept` method.

What I want to happen is to mandate that the implementing class `SpecificElement` will only accept visitors of type `SpecificVisitor` and nothing else, but still keep the signature of `Element`'s type interface at `Visitor`.

**UPDATE 1:** I added the type parameter `V extends Visitor<?>` in `Element`, then extended it with `SpecificElement extends Element<SpecificVisitor<?>` and was able to get what I want (stricter  parameter types in method accept): `<R> R accept(SpecificVisitor<?> visitor)`. However my problem now is that I want to determine the return type of the method `accept` based on the type parameter of the argument visitor (in this case `?`). Changing `?` to `R` causes compile error.

```
public interface Element<V extends Visitor<?> {
    public <R> R accept(Visitor<R> visitor);
}

public interface Visitor<R> {

}

class SpecificElement implements Element<SpecificVisitor<?>> {
    @Override                                    
    public <R> R accept(SpecificVisitor<R> visitor) { // error in type parameter R in SpecificVisitor
        return visitor.visitSpecificElement(this);
    }
}

class SpecificVisitor implements Visitor<Boolean> {
    public Boolean visitSpecificElement(SpecificElement element) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** I would like to write a family of Visitors for a family of Elements without giving up type safety. Notice the use of same Visitor subtype for an Element subtree. For Example:

```
--- Element -> Visitor<R>
       |
       |---- SpecificElement -> SpecificVisitor<R>
       |            |
       |            |---------SpecificElementA -> SpecificVisitor<R>
       |            |
       |            |---------SpecificElementB -> SpecificVisitor<R>
       |
       |---- FancyElement -> FancyVisitor<R>
                    |
                    |---------FancyElementA -> FancyVisitor<R>
                    |
                    |---------FancyElementB -> FancyVisitor<R>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a good solution to this without multiple type bounds that include type variables, or higher-kinded types, neither of which is supported by Java.

Comment: Maybe it would help people find appropriate work-arounds if you included info or examples of how this will be useful? (Compared to simply defining `SpecificElement` and `SpecificVisitor` without superclasses.)

Comment: @DanGetz currently, I am inclined to think that this is not supported in Java. But I added more explanations as to what I want to happen above.

Comment: @DanGetz I posted updates in question.

Comment: Can you give an example of code you want to write that uses an `Element` or `Visitor` generically? That might help in finding a workaround.

Comment: Added diagram above. Hopefully it shows what I am after.

Comment: Yes, that does help. But I still can't imagine how the user would *use* `Element` or `Visitor` generically.

Comment: for example, there is an object ``fancyElementA`` of type ``FancyElementA``, I would like to pass in ``isFancyEnoughChecker`` which is an instance of ``IsFancyEnoughChecker`` which extends ``FancyVisitor<Boolean>``. It should go like ``Boolean isFancy = fancyElementA.accept(isFancyEnough)``. This class ``IsFancyEnoughChecker`` should only be usable for ``FancyElement``s without me having to rewrite the accept method for each Subgroup of element/visitor that appears. On the top of my mind, I can probably say Expression trees are one application for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished, as long as you know your subtypes you want to use in advance. (You're using the visitor pattern, so you need to know all the element types in advance, anyway.) The important thing is to build your `Visitor` interface from the bottom up, not the top down:

```
public interface ElementVisitor<R> extends SpecificVisitor<R>, FancyVisitor<R> {
}

public interface Element {
    public <R> R accept(ElementVisitor<R> visitor);
}
```

Now `Element` subtypes will need a little boilerplate, so that they can implement the `Element` interface:

```
public abstract class FancyElement implements Element {
    public abstract <R> R accept(FancyVisitor<R> visitor);

    public <R> R accept(ElementVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return accept((FancyVisitor<R>) visitor);
    }
}
```

And then we can define the specific subtype visitors and elements:

```
public class FancyElement1 extends FancyElement {
    public <R> R accept(FancyVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public interface FancyVisitor<R> {
    public R visit(FancyElement1 e);
    // ...
}
```

… and repeat for `SpecificVisitor`.

Now you can define either a `FancyVisitor` that can only visit `FancyElement`s, a `SpecificVisitor` that can only visit `SpecificElement`s, or an `ElementVisitor` that can visit all `Element`s.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this version will be usefull.

make Element interface generic

```
interface Element<V> {
    <R> R accept(V visitor);
}
```

and SpecificElement should be so:

```
public class SpecificElement implements Element<SpecificVisitor> {
    public <R> R accept(SpecificVisitor visitor) {
        return visitor.visit();
    }
}
```

note that Element_s generic type V is not strict type, there can be anything. implementor of Element interface, can write any class in it, even if it doesn't implement Visitor interface. this is the disadvantage of this code.

Comment: Can I restrict V such that it must be a type extending an interface ``Visitor``?

Comment: My problem now is that my Visitor used to have a type parameter ``R`` that is provided at the method level. ``R`` at the method level clashes with the ``?`` in ``SpecificVisitor<?>`` at the class level. Is there some workaround to this?

Comment: Note that the return type of accept is dependent on the type of SpecificVisitor